# Pycharm Debugging

Tags: python, pycharm

Given the code below:

```
country_counter = {}

 def addone(country):
    if country in country_counter:
        country_counter[country] += 1
    else:
        country_counter[country] = 1

 addone('China')
 addone('Japan')
 addone('china')

 print (len(country_counter))

 confusion = {}
 confusion[1] = 1
 confusion[2] = 2
 confusion[1.0] = 4

 sum = 0
 for k in confusion:
    sum += confusion[k]

 print (sum)
```

I want to get show the stack trace of variable `confusion` and `country_counter` by putting breakpoints into it.
How can I do that when all the breakpoints options (such as step into, step over) are disabled?

[image]

Comment: Are you running it in debug mode?

Comment: @Alex No, Debug is thingee 5 by default. You can see that he's running it (thingee 4). User, you need to insert breakpoints in the appropriate locations, then 'debug' your file.

Comment: choose "Edit configurations" to set up a debug target, tool chain, source file, etc... I do not have access to my ide thus cannot verify though... or project property to setup the python

Comment: yeah i got that. How do i show the value of variable sum in each iteration of for loop?

Comment: choose the debug tab in the lower pane when it stops at a breakpoint. to the right of the tab a window shows all the variables and the values.

Answer (score 0):

Choose "Edit configurations" to set up a debug target, tool chain, source file, etc... I do not have access to my ide thus cannot verify though... or project property to setup the python.